# JavaScript not equals event from jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have created a tree in Javascript (using jstree) and I am listening to an for events when someone selects a node. I take the type of node from the data that is passed in and want to execute some code if the type is not default.

When I step through this in the debugger, type is "default", yet it steps into the if statement. What am I missing?

```
$('#mainTree')
  .on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var type = data.node.type;
      if (type != "default") {
```

*(I have tried !== as well)*

Comment: There's no obvious error here (for somebody not knowing that library). Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: are you sure that is `default` and not `'default'` or `"default"`

Comment: Show the code that triggers the event with the data.

Comment: I tried with != 'default' (and !== 'default') as well, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Barmar: The event is triggered within the jstree library (I simply added the code above to the existing tree. I will try to add the relevant parts to fiddle.

Comment: your code seem working on [this page](http://www.jstree.com/demo/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/514/

Change the if to make the `alert` appear. Are you sure you have the `types` plugin added, as in the demo above (the `core.plugins` config option)?